# Why my __init__.py doesn't work in the module?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to add 'project_root' into `__init__.py` and all modules can use it, but it doesn't work.

Environment: Python 3.7.0 MACOS MOJAVE

file structure

```
·
├── __init__.py
└── a.py
```

the codes in `__init__.py` file:

```
import sys

project_root = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
sys.path.append(project_root)
```

and in another file

```
print(project_root)
```

If I run `python a.py` in the same dir ,or run `python a.py` out of the dir, error are the same below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 1, in <module>
    print(project_root)
NameError: name 'project_root' is not defined
```

My question is why it doesn't work and how to fix it. 
Another question is what if you want to share some variables for other modules in a same package, how to do it?

Comment: It's unclear why you expected that *would* work. Declaring a variable in `__init__.py` doesn't make it in scope for every other file in the directory. I'd recommend reading e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank you, I will take a look at the link first. I want that work because I don't want to define `project_root` in every file.

Comment: Why would you need to define `project_root` in every file?

Comment: @jonrsharpe because I have to operate csv files in another dir, so I need to use project_root path to generate csv file path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us try to understand by example.

### Code and directory explanation:

Suppose we have the following directory and file structure:

```
dir_1
    ├── __init__.py
    └── a.py
b.py
```

`__init__.py` contains:

```
import sys,os

# Just to make things clear
print("Print statement from init")

project_root = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
sys.path.append(project_root)
```

`a.py` contains:

```
def func():
    print("func from a.py")
```

### Let us start importing things:

Suppose you start with having the following code in `b.py`:

```
from dir_1.a import func

func()
```

Executing the above will give the following output:

> Print statement from init 
>   func from a.py

So, from the above, we understand that the `print` statement from `__init__.py` is being executed. Now, let's add `print(project_root)` in `b.py`:

```
from dir_1.a import func

func()
print(project_root)
```

Executing the above will result in an error saying:

> ... 
>   NameError: name 'project_root' is not defined

This happened because we did not have to import the `print` statement from `__init__.py` it just gets executed. But that is not the case for a variable.

Let's try to import the variable and see what happens:

```
from dir_1.a import func
from dir_1 import project_root

func()
print(project_root)
```

Executing the above file will give the following output:

> Print statement from init 
>   func from a.py 
>   /home/user/some/directory/name/dir_1

*Long story short*, you need to import the variable defined in `__init__.py` 
 or anywhere else in order to use it.

Hope this helps : )

Comment: Thanks @Amit Yadav, I understand your example.So if I want to use the `project_root` argument inside the package (files in dir), `__init__.py` doesn't work because it won't be execute while I execute file in the dir.

Answer (score 0):

You have to import the variable:

```
from dir import project_root
```

Where dir is the directory you are in

Comment: I tried, suppose the dir is `tmp`, I got the error
```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 1, in <module>
    from tmp import project_root
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tmp'
```